# How to move an object over a curve using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-animate

[image]

I want to move an object over these curves using javascript. when i click an object the object moves on the curve.I tried animate methode of jquery plugin but it did not work.
I could not find the way to do this using javascript.Is it possible using SVG or it can be done using javascript.

please any one can guide me

Answer (score 1):

With jquery path you could define several javascript animations:
https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path

Answer (score 0):

you can see my code work here [Demo jsFFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/XfvpL/6/)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <line class="line_svg" x1="75" y1="100" x2="275" y2="100" />
    <line class="line_svg" x1="75" y1="250" x2="275" y2="250" />
    <line class="line_svg" x1="75" y1="100" x2="75" y2="400" />
    <line class="line_svg" x1="175" y1="100" x2="175" y2="400" />
    <line class="line_svg" x1="275" y1="100" x2="275" y2="400" />
    <line class="line_svg" x1="75" y1="400" x2="275" y2="400" />
    <path id="path1"  
     d="M75,250 C 100,50 250,50 275,250"
     d="M 275,250 C 250,400 100,400 75,250" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="7.06"  />
      <circle cx="75" cy="250" r="18" fill="blue"  />
      <circle cx="175" cy="100" r="18" fill="blue"  />
      <circle cx="275" cy="250" r="18" fill="blue"  />
      <circle cx="175" cy="400" r="18" fill="blue"  />

<path d="M-25,-12.5 L25,-12.5 L 0,-87.5 z"  fill="yellow" stroke="red" stroke-width="7.06"  >
    <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            begin="0s"
            dur="10s"
            type="rotate"
            from="0 -100 -110"
            to="360 150 150"
            repeatCount="1" />
    <animateMotion dur="11s" repeatCount="1" rotate="auto" >
       <mpath xlink:href="#path1"/>
    </animateMotion>

    <circle id="pointA" cx="75" cy="250" r="5" />
</svg>
```

Comment: you did great work but your code is actually creating a path and then object moves over it .what i want is the picture i have shown is image i want to move object over this curve image @user2015930